# how to handle ACK/NAK in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring-integration, tcp

My Tcp server is working well with spring integration. I use the following beans:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpServerFactory"
    type="server"
    port="9000"
    single-use="true"
    so-timeout="10000"
    using-nio="false" 
    serializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
    deserializer="connectionSerializeDeserialize"
    task-executor="taskExecutor"
    />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>
<bean id="connectionSerializeDeserialize" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayStxEtx"
    connection-factory="tcpServerFactory"
    request-channel="requestChannel"
    error-channel="tcpErrorChannel"
    reply-timeout="10000"
    />
```

My client sends ACK if it received the message properly formatted (data enclosed between STX and ETX). If there is any error in receiving the data, it will send NAK. On the Tcp Server, I need to read the ACK/NAK sent by the client. If client send ACK then, server does not need to do anything. If client sends NAK, Server needs to re-send the data back to client.

is there any serializer which handles ACK/NAK in spring integration?
if not, please suggest where and how to handle ACK/NAK?

Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the ack/nack sent by the client? What does your current `connectionSerializeDeserialize` look like?

Comment: client sends ACK as a single byte 0x06. (or NAK as 0x15). My serializer bean is from spring <bean id="connectionSerializeDeserialize" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayStxEtxSerializer"/>

Comment: OK; in that case you'll need a custom `Deserializer` that detects the ack/nack and otherwise delegates to the `Byt‌​eArrayStxEtxSerializ‌​er`. Since this is an (n)ack to a response you will want to discard it (not forward it as a message) so the deserializer should return null. Be aware, however, that the `TcpMessageMapper` will log a WARN log, so you might want to set its logger to only log at ERROR level. For the NACK, you will have to return some value that will be wrapped in a message and your flow will have to handle it.

Comment: Thanks Gary, custom Deserializer seems to be the way to go.